SolidWorks API Delete Revision Table
The issue I am having is using the API I can get a macro to sometimes delete the table.  On some drawings method A works, on some method B, and others nothing works.  I suspect it may have something to do with one source template being created in France, but I am not sure.  I also have a suspicion that the location of the table may be a factor.
I am NOT a programmer, I am usually able to combine information from here, some faint recollection of VB back in college, and recording some items, then making it work.  Usually I am successful, but this one has me stumped.
Method A:
'Captures the item name of the table
    sName = swTable.GetAnnotation.GetName & "@Sheet1"
    
'Deletes the table
Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2(sName, "REVISIONTABLE", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
Part.EditDelete

I have also added the vSheetNames (from method B) to the above to accommodate the sheet name changing, or being in French
Method B (found on web):
vSheetNames = swDraw.GetSheetNames
For i = 0 To UBound(vSheetNames)
    swDraw.ActivateSheet vSheetNames(i)
'    Debug.Print vSheetNames(i)
    Set swSheet = swDraw.GetCurrentSheet
    Set RevTableAnn = swSheet.RevisionTable
    
    If Not RevTableAnn Is Nothing Then
'        Debug.Print "Revision Table is SOMETHING! Double check for revTableFeat now!"
        Set revTableFeat = RevTableAnn.RevisionTableFeature
        If revTableFeat Is Nothing Then
'            Debug.Print "Revision table feature is nothing but a revision table exists!"
            Set swTableAnn = RevTableAnn
            Set swAnn = swTableAnn.GetAnnotation
        
            boolstatus = swAnn.Select3(False, swSelData)
            bRet = swModelDocExt.DeleteSelection2(swDeleteSelectionOptions_e.swDelete_Absorbed)
            Debug.Print "Revision table annotation deleted? " & bRet
        

        Else
'            Debug.Print "Revision table feature is present! Delete it!"
            Set swFeat = RevTableAnn.RevisionTableFeature.GetFeature
            bRet = swFeat.Select2(False, 0)
            bRet = swModelDocExt.DeleteSelection2(swDeleteSelectionOptions_e.swDelete_Absorbed)
        End If
    Else
'        Debug.Print "Revision Table is nothing! Sheet can be skipped!"
    End If
    

Next

Method A worked for all of our original sheet formats, but has never worked on the French versions. Method B works on some, and others it does not.  I am at a loss.  Happy to share more information and items to test with.  Would appreciate any help!
Thank you.**
I have tried multiple methods (shown above) as well as recording myself and comparing the data - it looks the same?

Guess that your first method works on a drawing thath only has one sheet named Sheet1, is that right? And maybe the sheet name of the french drawings are Feuil1?

Correct, but I have accounted for that adding a variable to pull sheet name - yet it still only works sometimes

Ok. Have you tried to debug your code line by line, to check if the code loops through all the sheets,  and through all the the RevisionTable? Also uncomment the Debug.Print lines while debugginf, it will surelly help you. Your second code should be working. Maybe something else is happennig in code that you are not sharing? Are you locking the FeatureManager? Do you have Rebuilds in your code?

If you run code B twice on the same Drawing what happens? Do you stil have the same tables undeleted? Are the undeleted tables really RevisionTables?

Interesting - running it twice did work - and debug showed that I was actually deleting it, but then adding it back.

Because there were multiple sheets and table still present on another sheet

And the additional sheet only has a name, no number - so my For i loop only saw one sheet.

This is the method that I typically use. It selects the annotation directly without the need to deal with features/sub-features on the feature tree. I believe working with the features requires that each sheet be activated prior to getting and selecting the revision table which takes a good bit more time than this.
It's possible that the use of swModelDocExt.DeleteSelection2 could be causing your issue as well.
Sub main()
    Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel As ModelDoc2
    Dim swSheet As Sheet
    Dim swRevTable As RevisionTableAnnotation
    Dim swTable_Rev As TableAnnotation
    Dim swAnno As Annotation
    
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    
    Set swCurFeature = swModel.FirstFeature
    
    While Not swCurFeature Is Nothing
        If swCurFeature.GetTypeName2 = "DrSheet" Then
            Set swSheet = swCurFeature.GetSpecificFeature2
            Set swRevTable = swSheet.RevisionTable
            
            If Not swRevTable Is Nothing Then
                Set swTable_Rev = swRevTable
                
                Set swAnno = swTable_Rev.GetAnnotation
                swAnno.Select3 False, Nothing
                swModel.EditDelete
            End If
        End If
            
        Set swCurFeature = swCurFeature.GetNextFeature
    Wend

End Sub


I attempted this, setting swCurFeature as a Feature, and adding my drawing sheet name, but it never selected the table

If you changed ‘DrSheet’ to something else then it won’t work. It is the name of the feature type, not the name of the sheet. As is, this should delete your rev tables without a modification.
